# How do you read data from a socket into an offset of an existing buffer?

Tags: sockets, tcp, rust

As per my understanding of TCP, if I send X bytes to a socket, it is pretty much guaranteed that it will get there, although it is possible that the payload may split and arrive in two separate parts (So if I am waiting for a 25 byte packet I may get 20 bytes, then an additional 5 on the next read). I have never seen this happen, but I want to be covered when it does.

In the past I have usually designed my socket reads to account for this - reading incoming bytes into a buffer, and then continuously checking the size of the buffer. If there is enough data for an entire packet, handle that packet, remove the bytes from the front of the buffer, and continue.

I am now trying to program a similar system in Rust, using `mio` for TCP sockets. My buffer is just an array: `[u8; MAX_BUFFER_SIZE]` and here's my socket read code:

```
loop {
    // Read until there are no more incoming bytes
    match socket.read(&mut buffer) {
        Ok(0) => {
            // Socket is closed, Client has disconnected!
            // (perform disconnection here)
            break;
        },
        Ok(read_bytes) => {
            println!("Read {} bytes from client", read_bytes);
        },
        Err(e) => {
            if e.kind() == io::ErrorKind::WouldBlock {
                // Socket is not ready anymore, stop reading
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This does not support reading any split data, because the `read` function just overwrites the data at the beginning of the buffer, instead of appending each subsequent call to the end. In C# and C++ there is an offset parameter you can supply to the equivalent call to allow this behavior, but I cannot figure out how to do that with `mio`. The fact that I can't find any offset parameter leads me to believe that I am missing something important in my understanding of the `read` function.

How would I program socket reading that accounts for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The fact that I can't find any offset parameter leads me to believe that I am missing something important

Yes, but it has nothing to do with sockets specifically. Rust has *slices*, a more general solution. To get a subset of your buffer, take a slice starting at the desired offset. The data will be read into the beginning of the slice which is the same as the offset of the original buffer:

```
socket.read(&mut buffer[offset..])
```

When you are done reading, you can take a slice to prevent looking at non-useful trailing data in the buffer:

```
let my_data = &buffer[..total_read_bytes];
// do something with my_data
```

A complete example:

```
use std::io::prelude::*;

const MAX_LEN: usize = 64;

fn main() {
    let dummy_data = b"this is a very long bit of data";
    let mut dummy_data = &dummy_data[..];

    let mut buffer = [0; MAX_LEN];

    let mut offset = 0;
    offset += dummy_data
        .by_ref()
        .take(4)
        .read(&mut buffer[offset..])
        .unwrap();
    offset += dummy_data
        .by_ref()
        .take(4)
        .read(&mut buffer[offset..])
        .unwrap();

    let final_data = &buffer[..offset];

    let s = std::str::from_utf8(final_data);
    println!("{:?}", s);
    assert_eq!(s, Ok("this is "));
}
```

---

You may also be interested in [`Read::read_exact`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_exact):

> This function reads as many bytes as necessary to completely fill the specified buffer `buf`.